# Update DataGridView to DataSet

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, dataset

I'm displaying information from a dataset in a datagridview. How do I update the dataset with the data in the datagridview after it's modified? (automaticly or through button) Using winforms,in visual studio 2010, c#

Answer (score 0):

The first, you should create a new datatable to contains data from Datagridview
After that, in the buttun are:(i'm connecting with database is accsess(sql is the same))

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("Your query", con);
        OleDbCommandBuilder cmdb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adp);

        adp.Update(dt);
```

// con: the variable name to connecting with database

Comment: If I use "(DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource" it says it cannot be converted to Data Table. So I used "dataGridView.DataSource as DataTable" instead. Now the only problem is on the last line, while running the program, it says that dt cannot be null. I've checked, the gridView isn't empty, yet dt is truly null. How can that be? (If it's relevant I'm using SqlCe because I don't have OleDb).

Comment: First, you are using vb.net?

Comment: Second,  dt null is right because you need create a dataset to fill data from sql to dataset:

   public DataSet FillData()
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Your query", con);

            OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            adp.Fill(ds, " nameYourTable");

            con.Close();

            return ds; ;

        }
and then creatte a button to event capture 
dataGridView1.DataSource = FillData().Tables[0];